# Scala rep() and associativity

Tags: scala, grammar, context-free-grammar, bnf

I want to express this grammar in scala StdTokenParsers:

```
expr -> expr ("+"|"-") ~ muldivexpr | muldivexpr
```

"+" and "-" is left associative.

The grammar is left recursive so it caused infinite recursions. I can rewrite to remove left recursion, but it will change to right associativity.

Now I am planning to use scala rep() to rewrite it as:

```
expr -> rep(muldivexpr ("+"|"-")) ~ muldivexpr
```

but will rep() that change the associativity? How does rep() work in this case?

I am asking this question because I have to output the AST in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely looking for:

```
chainl1[T](p: => Parser[T], q: => Parser[(T, T) => T]): Parser[T]
```

The general idea is `p` is an operand, and `q` is a separator yielding a function which can combine two operands, e.g.

```
chainl1(muldivexpr,
  "+" ^^^ { (l: Expr, r: Expr) => Addition(l, r)    }
| "-" ^^^ { (l: Expr, r: Expr) => Subtraction(l, r) }
)
```